# A problem with calculus..

Tags: calculus, physics, classical-mechanics

> A body is dropped in a well and it travels $p$ depth in $t$  time interval. The relation is $$p(t)=\frac4{4+t^2}+0.8t-1.$$ Find the velocity and acceleration.

Now if I differentiate the expression by considering "$-1$" as a constant, it vanishes and velocity, $v=\dfrac{(8t)}{(4+t^2)^2} +0.8$ Again if I simplify the 1st term with "$-1$" the velocity, $v=\dfrac{-(8t)}{(4+t^2)^2}$. The book considers the later one as answer.  why?

Comment: Check your derivative for $p$, seems to be off by a minus sign. I am not sure what you mean by "simplify the 1st term with -1", are you taking the second derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your velocity expression is slightly incorrect,

recall that $$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{u(x)}{v(x)}=\frac{u'(x) v(x)-v'(x) u(x)}{(v(x))^2}$$

So, evaluating $$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{4}{4+t^2}=\frac{0-8t }{(4+t^2)^2}$$
So now you can see where the '$-$' sign comes from.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. So silly mistake.. Thank you again.